# How to print tweet from from specific profile in python using twitter api

Tags: python, twitter

I want to print the tweets from a profile but I can't. I guess that I'm not using the right commands or something. I'm new in coding so I don't uderstand to much about api's.
I can get info about the profile so the conection is right.

```
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import API
from tweepy import Cursor
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
from collections import Counter
import sys
import tweepy

#I don't put the secret token and all of that


auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
auth_api = API(auth)

account_list = ["jufut390"]

if len(account_list) > 0:
  for target in account_list:
    print("Getting data for " + target)
    item = auth_api.get_user(target)  
    print("screen_name: " + item.screen_name) 


  #Get info about tweets
    end_date = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=5)
    for status in Cursor(auth_api.user_timeline, id=target, tweet_mode = "extended").items():   
      #print tweets   
      if status.created_at < end_date:
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line :

```
for status in Cursor(auth_api.user_timeline, id=target, tweet_mode = "extended").items():
```

The `id` parameter has no effect. It should be `user_id` and a valid user ID (numeric) See : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html

In you case, you can use the `screen_name`.

Secondly, you say you want to print the tweets, so write a `print`. Try this :

```
#Get info about tweets
end_date = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=5)
for status in Cursor(auth_api.user_timeline, screen_name=item.screen_name, tweet_mode = "extended").items():   
    print(status.full_text)
    if status.created_at < end_date:
        break
```